# getting a keyerror 'item'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-telegram-bot

i got an issue with BeautifulSoup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Милена\Documents\html\pricetracker bot\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    price=soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')['item']
  File "C:\Users\Милена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'item'
```

I am totally new to python and telegram-bot, so I don't know what issues I have. Did I make a mistake in the code below or with div itself?

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL='https://www.sulpak.kz/'
TOKEN=os.getenv('TOKEN')
CHAT_ID=os.getenv('CHAT_ID')
TELEGRAM_API_SEND_MSG=f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage'

items = [
    'g/noutbuk_asus_zenbook_um431da_am020t_r785uw_90nb0pb3_m01810_62_1747',
    'g/smartfon_samsung__galaxy_note20_gray_sm_n980fzagskz_77_2514'
]

for item in items:
    url=BASE_URL + item
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    name = soup.select_one('h1[class="product-container-title"]').get_text()
    price=soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')['item']

    data = {
        'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
        'text': f'*${price}*\n[{name}]({url})',
        'parse_mode': 'Markdown'
    }

    r = requests.post(TELEGRAM_API_SEND_MSG, data=data)
```

Comment: The traceback tells you what the issue is. The `soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')` has no key `item` so it can't provide the respective value and returns a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to `soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')` not returning an object that contains an item with the key `item`.  So when you apply `['item']` to that return value, you are getting that error.  I'd recommend that you assign the value `soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')` to a variable, and then check first to see if it contains the key `item`, and then do whatever is appropriate in the case where it does not. For example:

```
priceDiv=soup.select_one('div[class="current-price"]')
if 'item' not in priceDiv:
    ... do here whatever is appropriate when `item` is not found ...
price = priceDiv['item']
```